# How to simulate IV model?

Tags: correlation, simulation, instrumental-variables

Suppose I have a structural equation
$$y=\beta D+\alpha X+\epsilon,\;\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$$
and a first-stage equation
$$D=\gamma Z+\eta X+\xi,\;\xi\sim N(0,1)$$
where $D$ is a continuous endogenous variable, and $X$ is exogenous, $Z$ is an instrumental variable that takes a binary value 0 or 1.

I want to simulate this IV model, but I'm quite confused how $X$ serves a place here, and I'm finding it difficult to fit $X$ into my simulation.

I simulate $Z$ first:

```r
z <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
```

Then I set the parameters $\gamma$ and $\eta$:

```r
gamma <- 0.1
eta <- 1
```

I also specify the distribution of $X$:

```
x <- rnorm(10, 1)
```

Then I generate the error terms:

```r
eps <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
xi <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
```

Then I generate $D$:

```r
d=gamma*z+eta*x+xi
```

Then what?

Comment: Then, you'd specify an equation for $y$ along the same lines. Also, to create endogeneity it can be helpful to draw $\epsilon$ and $\xi$ from a multivariate normal with correlation.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for the comment! May I ask how to create $y$? Do I need to specify $\beta$ and $\alpha$? Much thanks!

Comment: Yes, just like you proceeded with $\gamma$ and $\eta$ for the first stage, we also need to pick parameter values for the structural equation when simulating data.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks! May I ask how I could "recover" the parameters? Do I simply use `ivreg`?

Comment: No, in a simulation, you'd set them like you did for $\gamma$ and $\eta$. You cannot do `ivreg` yet as you do not have a dependent variable.